# Multiple-File-Upload, onchange-action not triggering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a Website which requires me to enable a multiple-File-upload for the user.
I have the following **input-field**:

```
<div class="carousel-item carousel-custom-item active input-wrapper" >
    <input class="d-none" type="file" id="files-upload" name="files" multiple="multiple">
    <label id="files-upload-label" for="files-upload"><i class="fas fa-plus plus fa-4x"></i></label>
</div>
```

I want to directly display the new Image on the Website and am currently using the following code:

```
window.onload = function () {
$("#files-upload").change(function() {
    console.log(this.files);
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          document.querySelector(".carousel-inner").innerHTML += `
          <div class="carousel-item w-100 h-100 carousel-custom-item">
                <img class="d-block w-100 object-fit carousel-custom-item" src=` + e.target.result + ` alt="slide-element">
          </div>`
          $("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('next')
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      }
});
}
```

Uploading just one Image-File is no problem, everything works as expected. But when clicking the upload-label again and submitting an image, it doesn't get displayed anymore. After some debugging (i.e. `console.log`-stuff :D) i found out, that the `onchange`-event doesn't get triggered. Whats the Problem?

Thanks for the Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are uploading multiple files at once, you must set your input name attribute as an array this way:

```
<div class="carousel-item carousel-custom-item active input-wrapper" >
    <input class="d-none" type="file" id="files-upload" name="files[]" multiple="multiple">
    <label id="files-upload-label" for="files-upload"><i class="fas fa-plus plus fa-4x"></i></label>
</div>
```

Note the `name="files[]"`, then you will have in the console the complete FileList object:

[image]

**EDIT**

I commented the line `$("#carouselExampleIndicators").carousel('next')` because causes an Exception (for missing plugin).

That code, as you shared it, inserts the first image into .carousel-inner div. If you would like to insert all the selected images... then you need a forEach loop inside the change function...

Just hit F12 in Chrome to see the console output.

Live jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zsecp6Ld/

**EDIT 2**

Here you have a jsfiddle the way you must do it if you want to insert all the images selected...

```
window.onload = function () {
$("#files-upload").change(function() {    

    [].forEach.call(this.files, function(file, index){

         var reader = new FileReader();

       reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
        return function(e) {

            console.log(theFile);

          // Render the image.
          var div = document.createElement('div');
          div.className = 'carousel-item w-100 h-100 carousel-custom-item';
          div.innerHTML = '<img src="'+e.target.result+'" />';
          $(".carousel-inner").append(div);
        };
      })(file);

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    });    
});
}
```

Display all the images: https://jsfiddle.net/jktc1whb/

Comment: strangely i still get the same result. How did you generate the output shown in your Image? Did you use the code from the question? If not, can you post it?

Comment: @Sarius, just for fun, I added another fiddle the way you could do it if you need to append all the selected images...